# PHP mod_rewire entire site, and rewriting image URLs?

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I have pretty much developed an entire site and was foolish to not implement mod_rewrite. I wish to do so now, and did a test page. The mod_Rewrite works perfectly, but I then have the issue of all of the imaegs being linked to the new pages URL, for example:

```
www.mysite.com/county/Kent.html
```

from

```
www.mysite.com/sector.php?county=kent
```

It works great, but then when I am on the new link the URL for images changes to this.

```
mysite.com/county/images/widMot.png
```

As if the 'images' folder is in the 'county' folder which actually doesn;t exist. Is there a rewrite rule, which will ignore this image link change? Or something I am missing?

EDIT: As requested:

```
...
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^county/([^/]*)\.html$ /sector.php?county=$1 [L]
...
```

EDIT: The solution the answer posted was excellent, and resolved the image issue, but I was then stuck with an issue of my css files being put after /images/ directory. Ofc a simple fix would be place them in there, but is there no other way?

Comment: Please show us the htaccess you've setup now.

Comment: You are trying to say that when you put mysite.com/county/images/widMot.png it is not redirecting right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the `<base>` HTML tag.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

It allows you to define the base URL of your site, after that, any link built like `/images/someimage.png` will direct you to the root directory's `images/`.

*EDIT:*
To be more specific, all relative URLs starting with a forward slash `/` will begin immediately after domain name.

Comment: Any idea how I would prevent it looking for CSS files in /county/ aswell?

Comment: Well, the same method will work there too, if it's the same situation. If not, I guess we'll need either a new thread, or a new set of details.

Comment: well what would I do for base? As it slaps rather /images/ before it, or /county/

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule YOUR REWRITE RULE
</IfModule>
```

Should pass everything to your rewrite rule, unless the requested URL is an actual file on the server.

Comment: Works for the CSS files but not images :/